# docker build error (apt-utils is not installed, cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists': Directory not empty)

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to build a docker image using the following command

```
docker build -t blog .
```

and the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4


RUN apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
      postgresql-client \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists


WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile* .
RUN bundle install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

the result I get is the following:

```
Step 1 : FROM ruby:2.4
 ---> ef296fcb8c7c
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update -yqq     && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends       postgresql-client       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
 ---> Running in 18bfd303925d
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-common.
(Reading database ... 21168 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-common_165+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-common (165+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-9.4.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-9.4_9.4.10-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-9.4 (9.4.10-0+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client_9.4+165+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client (9.4+165+deb8u2) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-common (165+deb8u2) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-9.4 (9.4.10-0+deb8u1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.4/man/man1/psql.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/psql.1.gz (psql.1.gz) in auto mode
Setting up postgresql-client (9.4+165+deb8u2) ...
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists': Directory not empty
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -yqq     && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends       postgresql-client       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

what is red are the 2 lines:

```
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed

rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists': Directory not empty
```

Why it cannot remove the directory since I'm using -rf?

Thank you!

Comment: I've run your Dockerfile locally and it works for me - What version of Docker are you using + what OS are you running?

Answer (score 3):

A few comments:

- Do not remove those files. Just run `apt-get update` again.  I'm part of the [Rocker project](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker) of (official) Dockerfiles for R, and we do see these timeouts.  They are harmless.
- If you insist (and I still recommend against) do `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` for the content *within* the directory.
- As for `apt-utils` missing, you could just install it.

Comment: As I read it, the command is `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists`, so you rfirst bullet seems strange?

Comment: No that is the same thing. _On a directory, without `-r`, you get the error the OP got_.  With `-r` added to `rm -r` it works.  The `-f` just "forces".

Comment: I might be really thick, but I really don't get you. The OP uses `-rf`. I know  that `-f` means force, but the fact it says `-rf` means the OP (also) uses `-r`. So saying "with `-r` added it works",  doesn't help: OP says they use `-rf`, which means that `-r` is supplied.

Comment: Yep. My bad. He does.  I still recommend against (it will upset `apt` and friends) but hey, his Dockerfile....   Thanks for catching that.  Answer edited.

Comment: I removed the "rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists" line. It executes now. I'm still not clear although on why it does not work since -rf means recursive force. Thank you for your help.